# How to Write a VBA Shell Script to Run a PHP Script on Variable Files

Tags: php, vba, excel, shell, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a shell script that will run a PHP script on a number of files at once (this requires using an exe file and a php file on a json file). The json file is the only one that is variable in this situation.

If I were using the command prompt manually, here's the command I would need to input to achieve the desired result-

```
C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/XAMPP/php/php.exe transcript.php transcribedfile.json
```

Cell G2 of my worksheet contains the json filename, so that's why I've activated it in the second line. Once I can get the shell script to work I will code in a loop that will cycle through all values in the G column, beginning with G2, until the ActiveCell value is "".

Here's what I've tried-

```
Sub Shell()
Range("G2").Activate
Dim strProgramName As String
Dim strArgument As String

strProgramName = "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\XAMPP\php\php.exe transcript.php " & ActiveCell.Value
strArgument = "/G"

Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

When I run the sub I get a "File Not Found" error. I tested strProgramName and found that I could get php.exe to run if I cut the code off at that point, but I would need it to recognize the whole string.

Any ideas would be welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does php.exe know where to find those two files? You might consider passing the full paths (and don't for get the quote the paths if they might contain spaces)

Comment: set your PHP path environmental value, then you can just call php without the path.  That probably wont solve the problem but it will make life easier.

Comment: @TimWilliams- they are all located within the same directory. How would I include the full paths? Sorry, I'm very very new to this.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - At the moment, I don't have admin access to this computer, so I can't change those values.

Comment: "same directory" as what - the executable, or your workbook?

Comment: Also - you need a space before the "/G" switch

Comment: The executable. I've added the space.

Comment: Why not host the PHP online, run the VBA and add a GET parameter at the end of the PHP filename, then in the PHP program you use the GET to read the Json file?

Comment: @Andreas I appreciate the suggestion but that is far beyond my skill level.

Comment: As far as I can see it looks like a simpler solution than your current. Do you have a place on the web to host? Using GET is as simple adding `?key=value` at the end of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do this:

```
Const PHP_PATH As String = "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\XAMPP\php\"
Dim strProg As Variant

strProg = """{pth}php.exe"" ""{pth}transcript.php"" ""{pth}" & _
          Range("G2").Value & """ \G"

strProg = Replace(strProg, "{pth}", PHP_PATH)
Debug.Print strProg '<< pass this to Shell
```

Comment: Incredible, I am in awe of your skills. That worked perfectly. My only concern now is to include a loop that will cycle through each value in column G, beginning with 2, until the value is blank. I tried coding it in myself but I ended up creating an infinite loop. How would I do that using your method? Thank you so much!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out myself. I had just coded the end value improperly. Thanks again, I will mark your answer correct.

Comment: FYI there are good libraries for parsing JSON in VBA.  E.g this one is very easy to use:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it when I have a chance.